# Radius of convergence of $\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{z^n}{e^{an}+1}, a \in \mathbb{C}$

Tags: complex-analysis, power-series, exponential-function

$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{z^n}{e^{an}+1}, a \in \mathbb{C}$$

I have some doubts on the result because of that complex parametre. I think that the radius is $R=0$, since the negative real axis of the complex plane makes the series diverge. Is it right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint. For $a:=x+iy\in\mathbb{C}$, we have that
$$|e^{an}+1|^{2}=|e^{xn}(\cos(ny)+i\sin(ny))+1|^{2}=e^{2xn}+2e^{xn}\cos(ny)+1.$$
Now evaluate the [radius of convergence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radius_of_convergence#Theoretical_radius), 
$$\limsup_{n\to +\infty} |e^{an}+1|^{1/n}$$
by considering three cases: $x>0$, $x<0$, $x=0$ (harder).

Comment: why it isn't: $e^{nx+niy}=e^{nx}(cos(ny)+isin(ny))$?

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the typo.

Comment: So after computing the limit $R=e^a$ ?

Comment: No, $e^a$ is not always a real number... It is $e^x$ when $x>0$ and $1$ if $x<0$. What happens if $x=0$?

Answer (score 0):

No. The radius of convergence is at least $e^{\operatorname{Re}a}$, because$$|z|<\operatorname{Re}a\iff\left|\frac z{e^a}\right|<1\implies\sum_{n=0}^\infty\left(\frac z{e^a}\right)^n\frac1{1+e^{-an}}\text{ converges.}$$But$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty\left(\frac z{e^a}\right)^n\frac1{1+e^{-an}}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{z^n}{e^{an}+1}.$$